# can anyone help me with this? i am getting an error that says cannot covert string to float in my training data

Tags: python, python-3.x, logistic-regression

i'm getting the following error. i don't know why

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-47db790ecefc> in <module>
      2 #Y = train_label.to_numpy()
      3 
----> 4 logreg = LogisticRegression().fit(train_X, train_Y)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"840343879668908032"'
```

this is the code i tried to execute

```
X = train_attr.to_numpy()
Y = train_label.to_numpy()

logreg = LogisticRegression().fit(train_X, train_Y)
```

Comment: Seems like there are additional quotes in the number string

Answer (score 0):

you have additional quotation marks in the string that you are trying to convert to float.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying to convert is this

> "840343879668908032"

but it should be this

> 840343879668908032

Python is taking double quotes as a part of the string, This may be because you would have used quotes multiple time like this

> sample_str = '"840343879668908032"' 
> or 
> sample_str2 = '"1321351"'

so you should remove the additional quotes and *for example* do

> sample_str = '840343879668908032'